# Othello Minimax Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to implement an artificial intelligence player for Othello using the Minimax algorithm. The computer plays decently, but its not great. Did I implement it correctly in my following code?

```java
Coordinate bestCoordinate = null;
public int minimax(MyButton[][] gameBoard, int depth, boolean maximizingPlayer) {
    if (depth == 0) {
        return evaluateBoard(gameBoard);
    }

    if (maximizingPlayer) {
        int bestValue = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        LinkedList<Coordinate> moves = generateMoves(gameBoard);
        for (Coordinate move : moves) {
            MyButton[][] newBoard = cloneBoard(gameBoard);
            processMove(newBoard, newBoard[move.getxCoordinate()][move.getyCoordinate()]);
            int v = minimax(newBoard, depth - 1, !maximizingPlayer);
            if (v > bestValue) {
                bestValue = v;
                bestCoordinate = move;
            }
        }
        return bestValue;
    }
    else {
        int bestValue = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        LinkedList<Coordinate> moves = generateMoves(gameBoard);
        for (Coordinate move : moves) {
            MyButton[][] newBoard = cloneBoard(gameBoard);
            processMove(newBoard, newBoard[move.getxCoordinate()][move.getyCoordinate()]);
            int v = minimax(newBoard, depth - 1, !maximizingPlayer);
            if (v < bestValue) {
                bestValue = v;
                bestCoordinate = move;
            }
        }
        return bestValue;
    }
}
```

Also, here is my evaluation function:

```java
public int evaluateBoard(MyButton[][] gameBoard) {

    int blackPieces = 0;
    int whitePiecess = 0;

    for (MyButton[] array : gameBoard) {
        for (MyButton button : array) {
            if (button.getBackground().equals(Color.black)) {
                blackPieces++;
            } else if (button.getBackground().equals(Color.WHITE)) {
                whitePiecess++;
            }
        }
    }

    int cornerBonus = 10;
    if (gameBoard[0][0].getBackground().equals(Color.BLACK)) {
        blackPieces += cornerBonus;
    }
    if (gameBoard[0][getBoardWidth() - 1].getBackground().equals(Color.BLACK)) {
        blackPieces += cornerBonus;
    }
    if (gameBoard[getBoardHeight() - 1][0].getBackground().equals(Color.BLACK)) {
        blackPieces += cornerBonus;
    }
    if (gameBoard[getBoardHeight() - 1][getBoardWidth() - 1].getBackground().equals(Color.BLACK)) {
        blackPieces += cornerBonus;
    }
    if (gameBoard[0][0].getBackground().equals(Color.WHITE)) {
        whitePiecess += cornerBonus;
    }
    if (gameBoard[0][getBoardWidth() - 1].getBackground().equals(Color.WHITE)) {
        whitePiecess += cornerBonus;
    }
    if (gameBoard[getBoardHeight() - 1][0].getBackground().equals(Color.WHITE)) {
        whitePiecess += cornerBonus;
    }
    if (gameBoard[getBoardHeight() - 1][getBoardWidth() - 1].getBackground().equals(Color.WHITE)) {
        whitePiecess += cornerBonus;
    }
    return whitePiecess - blackPieces;
}
```

(The computer always plays white, and the human is black).
I'm mainly unsure because the computer doesn't seem to protect corners, despite the bonus points that they give. Is there anything wrong with my code/logic?

Comment: Is there a problem with my recursion in the minimax method? I noticed that the computer always selects the first move available (the one highest up in the array), but i don't see where the problem is.

Comment: A questions and a hint. First, how is your generateMoves able to do its thing without knowing which side is moving? Secondly, the result of evaluateBoard must have its result's sign flipped for black. That is, if the score for a particular position is 27, say, seen from white's perspective, then it must be -27 seen from black's perspective, and so on.

Comment: But isn't that taken care of by my minimax method? I allow the board evaluation to be the same, but I alternate between maximizing and minimizing that number.

Comment: I don't have a reference implementation handy, but I think in your `minimax` function where you have `if (depth == 0) {...` you need to do something like `return maximizingPlayer ? evaluateBoard(gameBoard) : -evaluateBoard(gameBoard));`.

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't seem to change the game's behavior. I'm a bit perplexed, as no matter how large I make the corner bonus the computer still lets me get the corner squares. I'm not sure why that happens.

Comment: I think you only want to update your best coordinate if your depth is the initial depth.

Comment: That makes sense, but how would I do that? I'm a bit confused as to how to do that, given the recursive structure of the method.

Comment: To troubleshoot this, single-step the evaluation of simple test cases in the debugger - max depth of zero, then one, then two, and so on. Or, if you can't use a debugger for some reason, add logging code that shows what level you're at and what evaluation gives at that level.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be building out the entire tree properly; I think something is wrong in the for loop or in the recursion, but I can't figure out what. For some reason, it seems to only go down a few move paths.

Comment: Also, how would I update bestCoordinate only when it is on the top level? I don't know how to accomplish that in the recursion.

Comment: @MathLogic: see my answer

Answer (score 1):

You are updating your best move at each depth. Make a constant called SEARCH_DEPTH outside of your function that you use every time you call the function and do an if check:

```
if(depth == SEARCH_DEPTH) {
    bestCoordinate = move;
}
```

Also, assuming you are the maximizing player, you only want to set the move in the `if(maximizingPlayer)` block.

Answer (score 0):

I did not test your code out myself, but that is the minimax algorithm, and it appears to be written correctly (assuming your helper functions are implemented correctly). I have some points that might give you insight as to why your agent is not acting optimally:

1. I see your objective function is the number of pieces your agent has minus the number the opponent has, plus a bonus for corner pieces. This might seem like the best strategy, but I would read up on how good Othello players make their moves. Often, they try to flip only one piece if they can until late game, as they have more opportunities that way.
2. Minimax won't necessarily return the moves that will lead to capturing corners, even if you weigh them highly, because it might be undermined by the opponent's choice of moves. For example, lets say your algorithm looks three turns ahead on the computer's turn, so it first looks at a state where it capture a corner with a high objective function. However, your opponent will be choosing the route that will minimize your objective function, and as such the computer will not view moves moving towards capturing a corner piece as optimal because of the risk. I don't know how easy this will be, but if you can somehow visualize the tree, you might be able to figure out if this is the case.

Comment: You should at least test the code before posting an answer.

Comment: It is not possible to test the code without the helper functions. They are not trivial. I can say, however, that this is the correct algorithm. In light of your reply, I wrote this algorithm myself and tested it out. The only difference I had was I used a max/min function in place of the conditional to update the local variable "bestValue". It appears to be working.